# Why JSF implementation invoked response.getWriter() during file upload/download?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, download, jsf-2.2, ajax4jsf

This is my first question on SO.

I would like to create reporting file immediately after importing other file with some business elements.

After choosing import file with `h:inputFile`, I trigger Bean action with `h:commandButton` and nested `a4j:ajax`:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        try {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
            byte[] byteSourceExcelFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(sourceExcelFile.getInputStream());
            req.setAttribute("excel", DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byteSourceExcelFile));

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("importReport.jsf");  
            dispatcher.forward(req, res);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            FacesUtils.createErrorMessage(e.getMessage(), null, msgs);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            FacesUtils.createErrorMessage(e.getMessage(), null, msgs);
        } finally {
            facesContext.responseComplete();
            fileClear();    
        }
```

Request is forwarded to servlet, where import works well, but when I try to obtain object needed for output binary data:

```
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

I get error:

```
 org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0209E: Writer already obtained
```

I debugged servlet code and noticed that field `_gotWriter` is true in response object. This indicates that:

```
PrintWriter outputStream = response.getWriter();
```

is called. None of my filters did it. Also, other servlets which are used for obtaining data works fine.

Using MyFaces 2.2.3 as shared library on WebSphere 8.5.5.

**Mechanism described above works with Websphere 7 JSF implementation (Sun-RI 1.2) and Richfaces (3.3.3) component rich:fileUpload.**

1. What are possible causes of described state of response object?
2. Is there any way to replace `PrintWriter` object with `ServletOutputStream` object?

I hope this is appropriate way of asking question. I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Your code didn't call `response.getWriter()`, but the JSF implementation's framework did.

Comment: @Isaac Why is it happening in this particular case (not in others)?

Comment: had I known, I'd write it as an answer... but the error you're getting implies that *something* called `response.getWriter()`, so if it's not your code, then it must be the JSF implementation. I'm not a JSF expert so I can't comment further, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about `a4j:ajax` nested in `h:commandButton`.
It turns out, that this was cause of invoking `response.getWriter()` in the middle of request processing (I still don't know where and why).

```
<h:commandButton action="#{listBean['processImport']}" > 
    <a4j:ajax  oncomplete="js();" execute="fileUploadId" render="fileUploadId"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

I removed `a4j:ajax` and file download works as it is supposed to.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{listBean['processImport']}" onclick="js();"> 
</h:commandButton>
```

Now I need to figure how to update desirable elements on jsf page. But it's other story...

## Appendix: JSF 1.2

It is worth to mention, that before migration from WAS-7 (Sun-RI 1.2) to WAS-8.5.5 (MyFaces 2.2.3) above mechanism works with combination:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{listBean['processImport']}" > 
    <a4j:support  oncomplete="js();" reRender="fileUploadId"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

but did not work with:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{listBean['processImport']}" oncomplete="js();" reRender="fileUploadId" />
```

**EDIT**: After last IE security update 14-037 (KB2962872) file is received by browser, but cannot be opened or saved anymore.

Answer (score -1):

response.getOutputStream() and response.getWriter() should not be invoked both. You need check if there is any output in the importReport.jsf. If yes, remove them or use a separated class to process import logic.

Comment: I'd expect this to break under WAS 7.0 as well. The OP says that the code works on WAS 7.